# Accesing the xml string values

Tags: xml, perl

```
 my $profile_xml = $li->request(
 request_url         => 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,positions,industry,distance)',
 access_token        => $access_token->{token},
 access_token_secret => $access_token->{secret},
 );

 my $parser = XML::Parser->new( Style => 'Tree' );
 my $tree   = $parser->parse( $profile_xml );
```

I have used the above code and got the below answer but i dont know how to access the from xml string

```
<person>
   <id></id>
   <first-name></firstname>
</person>
```

These are the some of the nodes are there in the string

> $VAR1 = [ 'person', [ {}, 0, ' ', 'id', [ {}, 0, 'bEdA7NgdV8' ], 0, '
>   ', 'first-name', [ {}, 0, 'imm' ], 0, ' ', 'last-name', [ {}, 0, 'dee'
>   ], 0, ' ', 'positions', [ { 'total' => '1' }, 0, ' ', 'position', [
>   {}, 0, ' ', 'id', [ {}, 0, '3454532' ], 0, ' ', 'title', [ {}, 0,
>   'Software Engineer' ], 0, ' ', 'start-date', [ {}, 0, ' ', 'year', [
>   {}, 0, '2003' ], 0, ' ', 'month', [ {}, 0, '6' ], 0, ' ' ], 0, ' ',
>   'is-current', [ {}, 0, 'true' ], 0, ' ', 'company', [ {}, 0, ' ',
>   'name', [ {}, 0, 'Ara Systems' ], 0, ' ', 'industry', [ {}, 0,
>   'Information Technology and Services' ], 0, ' ' ], 0, ' ' ], 0, ' ' ],
>   0, ' ', 'industry', [ {}, 0, 'Information Technology and Services' ],
>   0, ' ', 'distance', [ {}, 0, '0' ], 0, ' ' ] ];

Comment: Using XPath on XML is usually easier. Look at `XML::LibXML` module and the `findvalue` and `findnodes` methods.

Comment: can you little bit elaborate because i am stuck in this .

Answer (score 0):

Lib::XML wwould be much easier and robust, but here it is using XML::Parser.

```
use Data::Dumper;
$VAR1 = [ 'person', [ {}, 0, ' ', 'id', [ {}, 0, 'bEdA7NgdV8' ], 0, ' ', 'first-name', [ {}, 0, 'imm' ], 0, ' ', 'last-name', [ {}, 0, 'dee' ], 0, ' ', 'positions', [ { 'total' => '1' }, 0, ' ', 'position', [ {}, 0, ' ', 'id', [ {}, 0, '3454532' ], 0, ' ', 'title', [ {}, 0, 'Software Engineer' ], 0, ' ', 'start-date', [ {}, 0, ' ', 'year', [ {}, 0, '2003' ], 0, ' ', 'month', [ {}, 0, '6' ], 0, ' ' ], 0, ' ', 'is-current', [ {}, 0, 'true' ], 0, ' ', 'company', [ {}, 0, ' ', 'name', [ {}, 0, 'Ara Systems' ], 0, ' ', 'industry', [ {}, 0, 'Information Technology and Services' ], 0, ' ' ], 0, ' ' ], 0, ' ' ], 0, ' ', 'industry', [ {}, 0, 'Information Technology and Services' ], 0, ' ', 'distance', [ {}, 0, '0' ], 0, ' ' ] ];

print Dumper($VAR1->[1]->[3],$VAR1->[1]->[4]->[2]);

print Dumper($VAR1->[1]->[7],$VAR1->[1]->[8]->[2]);

$VAR1 = 'id';
$VAR2 = 'bEdA7NgdV8';
$VAR1 = 'first-name';
$VAR2 = 'imm';
```